# Is there a way to generate browser alerts inside gsp files?

Tags: javascript, grails

I want a way to generate browser alerts from inside my gsp files. Is this possible to do with Grails? Or do I have to embed JavaScript code somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to issue a window.alert (or any other type of browser alert) you will need to use javascript (or jquery, or whatever you choose). You can of course include this in your GSP but there is nothing in Grails or GSP inherently to do this.